# How to calculate rate parameter in Exponential distribution?

Tags: logarithms, random, exponential-distribution

I am having a random dataset which seems to have exponential distribution. It is generated using the formula given in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution)

```
x = log(1-u)/(−λ)
```

I am trying to reverse engineer, and trying to find out the rate parameter used in generating the data set. Can I calculate `λ` based on the set of data available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Given a random sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ drawn from an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$, namely $$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x > 0,$$ we observe that the likelihood given the sample is $$\mathcal L(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_X(x_i) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda n \bar x} \mathcal{1}(x_{(1)} > 0),$$ hence the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) = n \log \lambda - n \bar x \lambda.$$  The MLE is therefore $$\hat \lambda = 1/\bar x.$$  So all you would do is take the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of your sample, and this would be your estimate of the rate parameter.